# Why there is difference in evaluating same equation with google, RPN , and Javascript evaluator?

Tags: javascript, math, shunting-yard

`3 + 4 * 2 / ( 1 - 5 ) ^ 2 ^ 3`

This is the equation which I tried to solve using three different ways

This is the exact question from
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

I pasted the exact equation to different sites

What I get from google is =
`3.00012207031`  which was obtained by searching `evaluate  3 + 4 * 2 / ( 1 - 5 ) ^ 2 ^ 3`

From JavaScript Console answer was  `0`  (I just put the exact equation in JavaScript console no modification)

From shunting Yard algorithm,
answer = `0.0001678466796875 or (11 / 65536)` (written in javascript, and I tried it in online calculator too https://www.free-online-calculator-use.com/postfix-evaluator.html#)

What's the reason behind this ?

Comment: For one, `^`  is an [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR) in JavaScript.

Comment: My maths says it’s `11/4096`? May you clarify what is supposed to be divided by the right hand side? Is it just the 2? This equation is ambiguous

Comment: The reason is trivial: even if math is universal, any system operates with its own rules of interpretation. If you don't care about these rules, then your effort will be wasted.

Comment: @evolutionxbox shouldn't it be equivalent 3 + (8 / 4096), rather than to 11/4096?

Comment: Yea, division goes before addition...

Comment: @secan that’s why I think it’s ambiguous. Google and WolframAlpha say it’s `7 * (2/65536)`. Usage of brackets here would make it a lot clearer

Comment: Also my maths is wrong… 

Comment: @evolutionxbox: No, Wolfram [says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+%2B+4+*+2+%2F+%28+1+-+5+%29+%5E+2+%5E+3) it's `3 + 4 (2/(1 - 5)^2^3)`, where the multiplication after the `4` takes precedence over the addition in front of it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  There's a `3 + ` at the beginning and `+/-` has the lowest precedence so that gets added after everything else, which effectively means in this case that the answer has to be close to 3.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I do not know about Google and WolframAlpha; all I know is what I was taught at school (too many years ago): PEMDAS (Parenthesis, Exponents, Multiplications and Divisions, Additions and Subtractions); when two or more operations have the same priority (multiplication and division or addition and subtraction) you simply proceed left to right. ;) So, I would read it as `3 + ((4 * 2) / (((1 - 5) ^ 2) ^ 3))`

Comment: @cerbrus not sure why you said no. That’s the same formula, but where “mine” was mostly calculated.

Comment: @secan your brackets change the formula. It’s not 4*2

Comment: No, it's not the same, @evolutionxbox. Operator precedence! You've added `3+4` together, while that's the _last_ step in this whole calculation. I don't know how you got that result out of google or wolfram, but if you'd just dump `3+4*2/(1-5)^2^3` into either website, they'd _both_ tell you the answer is `3.00012207031`. Your `7*(2/65536)` results in `0.00021362304`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox as I mentioned, according to what I was taught, multiplications and divisions have the same priority therefore you execute them in the order they appear, left to right: `4 * 2 ÷ 4 => (4 * 2) ÷ 4 => 8 ÷ 4 => 2`, **not** `4 * (2 ÷ 4) => 4 * 0.5 => 2`

Comment: I did this in calculator too, the answer I got is `3.00012207031`. Is there something wrong with shunting yard algorithm for evaluating exactly this problem ??.  Or this question is not correct?. I found the same example on other sites too

Comment: @secan re-read Cerbrus' comment.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I specified in my first comment I do not know what Google or WolframAlpha do and why they do what they do. My comment is based exclusively on what I was taught at school about [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). Anyway, it is not worth arguing about it; I think we can agree that in most cases, the best approach is to add parentheses whenever a doubt might arise. ;)

Comment: @secan sorry, I’m not arguing. My original maths is wrong. Cerbrus gave a comment why and their suggestion is correct

Comment: Hello, Is there any problem with shunting yard algorithm on this specific problem ???

Comment: The output should be `3.001953125`, so the shunting algorithm website is incorrect. As pointed out previously `^` is the bit wise XOR operator and not the exponent operator. In my mind an accurate JavaScript version would be `3 + 4 * 2 / Math.pow(Math.pow(( 1 - 5 ), 2), 3)` which would give the same output as Google.

Comment: @evolutionxbox for javascript, we can simply replace ^ with **  LIKE THIS: `3 + 4 * 2 / ( 1 - 5 ) ** 2 ** 3`. So probably the site and my implementation is wrong